# DailyMotion API not returning JSON object?

Tags: jquery, json, api, getjson, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to access the DailyMotion API. Try running this in your JavaScript console:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.dailymotion.com/video/xirgl9?fields=id', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Anyone know why this doesn't work and returns code 200 but no data? Because if you manually type in the URL

```
https://api.dailymotion.com/video/xirgl9?fields=id
```

A proper JSON object does indeed return.

Answer (score 0):

this should be jsonp.  add `&callback=?` to the end of your url and you'll get the proper objects back.